# Derivation of the Einstein model for the specific heat of solids

Tags: solid-state-physics

I am sorry if this is not the most appropriate channel for this question, which may seem more like a History of Science question, but I imagined I could get a better answer here than anywhere else.

My question is the following: In the "Oxford Solid State Basics", the author shows the derivation of Einstein's model for the heat capacity of solids. It starts with the partition function and the quantised energy

$$
E_{n} = \hbar \omega (n + 1/2).
$$

The author, however, says that this happened 19 years before Schroedinger came up with his formula. Where did Einstein get this quantised energy expression to derive his result?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Remember that Einstein had quantized light (the photoelectric effect) well before Schrodinger came up with his wave equation for quantum mechanics. Quantum did not start with Schrodinger, he 'just' provided a master equation. (And, in reality, the Einstein heat capacity model just assumes the optical phonon modes oscillate at some same energy).

Comment: How did he arrive at the same expression for the energy of a quantum oscillator though? Is the +1/2 term irrelevant for the heat capacity? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, the zero-point energy is irrelevant for $c_v$.  The heat capacity is the derivative, a constant term does not matter.